# ActionBarActivity does not open menu item on a device with soft navigation buttons

Tags: android, android-menu, android-actionbaractivity

i extended `ActionBarActivity` and set a parent theme from `Theme.AppCompat`

i am having a problem that on a LG G2, the overflow menu shows up and works fine, but the soft menu button on the buttom of the phone does not open the menu,

trying the same thing on a SGS3, the overflow menu does not appear (that's ok, because it has actual buttons), and the menu button works fine,

if i try to extend `Activity` instead and change to an appropriate theme, the menu opens up on both phones.

i overridden `onMenuOpened` in `ActionBarActivity` and is called when using the G2, but the menu does not open.

why doesn't the menu open on the G2?

Answer (score 0):

Since `KITKAT` overflow action menu item is shown even if the device has a menu key. I believe this is intended behavior. When testing on older platforms this isn't an issue (as you tested on SGS3).

Comment: that's ok, but i think that the soft menu key should also open the overflow menu, isn't that the intended behavior?

Comment: It seems logical, in any case having a software menu key on an Android 4+ device is pretty idiotic idea. Are any other apps on this phone behaving like this?

Comment: yes for example google's own `photos` or `play store` both open their menu when i press the soft menu key